# How to save database locally with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

What's the best way to force Entity Framework to create a database in a specific folder location within a project, so that the database can be moved with a project in Visual Studio 2013?

[Connection strings for EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606) can set up what database is used, but I would like a physical copy of the database to be saved onto a thumb drive, in the same folder as my VS2013 web project.

I found out how to do this once, but am having trouble locating how to do this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the connection string, use "AttachDbFilename" property. For example,

```
"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDatabase.mdf;"
```

or,

```
"AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Me\MyFiles\BacklogTrackerDB.mdf;"
```

Ref the MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.